# Why won't Strimzi create external broker when nodeport listener is configured?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, strimzi

Using docker-desktop w/kubernetes in Windows 10

I cannot get my kafka image to expose external brokers using nodeport following [this guide](https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/04/23/accessing-kafka-part-2/)

Strimzi cluster-operator and entity operators are deployed - when I do

```
kubectl get deployments
```

the response is

```
NAME                         READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
my-cluster-entity-operator   1/1     1            1           27m
strimzi-cluster-operator     1/1     1            1           33m
```

but when I do

```
kubectl get svc
```

the response is

```
NAME                          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                               AGE
my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap    ClusterIP   10.101.45.155   <none>        9091/TCP,9092/TCP,9093/TCP            28m
my-cluster-kafka-brokers      ClusterIP   None            <none>        9090/TCP,9091/TCP,9092/TCP,9093/TCP   28m
my-cluster-zookeeper-client   ClusterIP   10.110.47.4     <none>        2181/TCP                              32m
my-cluster-zookeeper-nodes    ClusterIP   None            <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP            32m
```

I would think that an external bootstrap and external brokers would be started on 9094, but nothing appears. What am I doing wrong?

My kafka.yaml:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: my-cluster
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 3.2.0
    replicas: 3
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
      - name: tls
        port: 9093
        type: internal
        tls: true
      - name: external
        type: nodeport
        tls: false
        port: 9094
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 2
      default.replication.factor: 3
      min.insync.replicas: 2
      inter.broker.protocol.version: "3.2"
    storage:
      type: ephemeral
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 3
    storage:
      type: ephemeral
  entityOperator:
    topicOperator: {}
    userOperator: {}
```

Edit to include more resources:

status condition is showing the following:

Failure executing: GET at: https://10.96.0.1/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterrolebindings/strimzi-debezium-my-cluster-kafka-init.
Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn''t have access. Service
account may have been revoked. clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io
"strimzi-debezium-my-cluster-kafka-init" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:debezium:strimzi-cluster-operator"
cannot get resource "clusterrolebindings" in API group "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
at the cluster scope

Seems like an obvious enough message, I'm thinking I need to figure out how to configure the service account

Comment: The YAML looks good. But without the operator logs and the state of the resource from Kuberneter it is hard to say what the problem is. So you should share the log and share how the full resource looks like when you do `kubectl get kafka my-cluster -o yaml`.

Comment: Note: The link you've referenced is a post from 2019. You may want to cross reference to the [current docs](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/overview.html#configuration-points-common_str)